# React JS Navbar Header Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm following this tutorial : https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-containers.html and I have an issue with the Navbar.

Here's my code for App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import "./App.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <Link to="/">Scratch</Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Routes.js :

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./containers/Home";

export default () =>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
  </Switch>;
```

It compiled successfully but I have this error :

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely
forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might
have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

I noticed that if I remove the Navbar.Header part and leave only Navbar it's working.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you import the `NavBar` like this: `import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'`? Or maybe you are not exporting your `Routes` component as the `default` export?

Comment: If I put 'react-bootstrap/Navbar I have this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'Header' of undefined' and I edited the question with Routes.js code

Comment: [There doesn't seem to be a `Navbar.Header` component](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/navbar/#navbar-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial says you should install version [`0.32.4`](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/setup-bootstrap.html) - did you do that? The current version [doesn't have a `Navbar.Header` export anymore](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/commit/e33734edbc641be3208e30e2aa2f5c28273e909b#diff-9d651e5c92548c4d9e89560e0df67ce9).

Comment: This is where I made my mistake, I wanted to use the last version but didn't think of that. Thx :)

Comment: And looks like I was doing the same. Navbar.Header doesn't exist any more in React Bootstrap ('react-bootstrap'). Thanks for your help.